# SQL Server 2005 server totally crashed, how to get files?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Server with SQL Server 2005 is only readable running Ubuntu from CD. How can I

1. find the relevant files and
2. load onto a different server running SQL Server 2008?

Older back up files exist, but would prefer to use current files.

Answer (score 6):

> 1) find the relevant files

The mdf files are the database; the ldf files are the logs.

> 2) load onto a different server running SQL 2008?

Use the [Attach database instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx).